# Graphical results of Q-Learning: is improvement possible by parameter tweaking?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

From left to right:

- Maximum Q value for action selection (averaged)
- Train error (averaged)
- Reward from environment (averaged)

[image]

I run double Q-learning.

A behavioral policy is ε-greedy, ε constant decaying to 0.1.

I used learning rate decay as follows:

```
learning.rate = start_learn_rate / log(counter + 1), #decaying learning rate

optimizer = 'sgd'
start_learn_rate = 0.001
```

I observe degradation of the average reward after it hits its maximum, with a clear oscillation behaviour from high to low.

**Is this chart typical to TD (Q) learning routine?**

**Could you advise on what parameters could be changed to stabilize the result?**

**Why the models behave like that? Don't they ought to expose a stable behaviour when Q is stabilized?**

### Environment, agent actions, and reward structure

My task is quite specific. I model sequences of actions applied to a process generating time series for the purpose of making something like predictions.

[image]

Observe a sine function (timeseries). Agent gets information about lagged values (and some engineered features) of that process from it's PAST. Another part of environment consists of a series of PAST actions (i.e., past 10 actions).

Actions are:

- buy (green)
- hold (black)
- sell (red)

A return (basis for the reward) is generated when conditions meet:

- buy -> sell (close buy position and immediately enter sell)
- sell -> buy (close sell position and immediately enter buy)
- buy -> hold (close buy and wait for next action)
- sell -> hold (close sell and wait for next action)

The return is maximum (equals 2) when the agent keeps the series of one-type actions starting at hill and down to valley, and vice versa for other sign positions.

At this chart you could see that in the bottom plot the agent learned to guess the direction right in most cases, but the return is not maximized to the value of 2.

My goal is not just to observe the leraning statistics, but to find an optimal policy to be applied to an out of sample data, with further exploration and policy refinement.

My intuitive guess is that the learning rate is too high when theagent is close to optimality and is forced to escape the region:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I get almost perfect solution of the optimal policy in my toy task, however, the neural network is not quite stable, and I have to manually choose the moment to stop learning.

This is how the system evolved during training:

[image]

Again the optimality seems to be reached at some point (with later fluctuations).

The learning behaviour of the agent:

[image]

Note that after aprx. 30 000 iterations the anent starts to make clear sequences of actions leading to maximized reward.

At test (with greedy action selection) the behaviour is that:

[image]

And test trades are also pretty clear (not perfect though):

[image]

There are 2 points I want to improve:

- Stopping criteria for learning
- Stability of max-Q and averaged return (and sum of returns) during
  test.

Comment: Worth adding brief summary about your environment, because it could be important. Also, your third chart - is it the reward received during learning?
Or is it a separate assessment running the optimal policy (i.e. without $\epsilon$, using pure greedy selection over Q)?

Comment: Note if your goal is to receive maximum total reward *during learning*, you may prefer SARSA (or expected SARSA) over Q learning. If you just want to find an optimal policy, you should bear in mind that your learning graphs are not showing you the behaviour of the estimated optimal policy, but of the learning/exploring policy.

Comment: @Neil Slater, thank you. I updated my question. This is the learning phase. However, I have infinite sample number (I can learn all the time) and am free to stop the learning at any time. The rewards are accumulated using exploration = 0.1.

Comment: When you say "Another part of environment consists of a series of PAST actions (i.e., past 10 actions)." do you mean that is stored in the environment only (i.e. it is hidden from the agent), or is it presented to the agent as part of the state. Is the state fully observed - i.e. the current state is a perfect predictor of [a probability distribution over] next state and reward?

Comment: I mean that everything is available to agent: past values of the timeseries and past actions. The past actions are here to form up a stack of the history of environment snapshots. Given that the agent observes far enougn of the tomeseries past, and, the stack of actions made in that past, it knows how and in which conditions it has been behaving. Example of the environment that the agent observes: timeseries values for lags 1:16, diffrence of these values from moving average, actions made: 0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1. Where buy is 1, sell is -1, 0 is hold. At the moment agent is in sell position.

Comment: @Neil Slater, so following your comments it might be that learning reward seen is from the optimal policy but it is polluted with explorative actions? Ivmight need to run an out-of-sample test using greedy policy to undersrand if it is true or close to being true. I did not get why SARSA may show better learning rewards over Q-learning. Is that because the former works with exprolation ad the target policy?

Comment: SARSA will often show better rewards *during* training, since its policy evaluation allows for the possibility of making mistakes due to the exploration. See SARSA's behaviour in cliff walking example: https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788295758/9/ch09lvl1sec82/cliff-walking-example-of-on-policy-and-off-policy-of-td-control - note this means that SARSA may be slower to learn the optimal policy, but may achieve more moderate results whilst working towards it. Whilst Q-learning will encourage riskier behaviour during learning

Comment: @Neil Slater, I got it. I had read about Cliff World example you have cited. Indeed SARSA makes less fatal mistakes in there but would do worse after implementing the greedy version. I understand this part. Riskier behaviour in my example is closing positions soon, but that's not what I want to see. I am worried that the training average reward maximizing at 1 (1.2 as largest) is still kinda below the par. I tried running experiment with 0.0005 learning rate, and it took several hours to get to the same point with following degradation. I will try different parameter values, maybe it resolves.

Comment: @NeilSlater, hello. Could you kindly take a look at the updated part of my question? I have made some progress after following your insights (and changing the engineering of rewards). There are sources of instability that I sill don't convey.

Comment: I took a brief look. But it is too deep into the specifics of your project for me to attempt to answer.

Comment: @NeilSlater, thank you, I see. Nonetheless your comments did help me to move forward with it, so thanks!

Comment: @NeilSlater, I wished to add that if you ever become interested in the specifics of the RL for trading-like tasks, I am eager to share my scripts and know-how with you.